# Is it Possible to Rollback Table Deletion in Mysql

Tags: mysql

We Have Mistakenly Dropped a Table in my DB and am using MySql . Is it Possible to ROLL Back or any other options . Please Provide your Valuable Suggestions

Comment: Question 1: do you have backups? Question 2: Have you tested them?

Comment: no i don't have backups, tested means

Comment: And did you **drop** or **delete from** the table? Did you use `DROP TABLE t;` or `DELETE FROM t ;`? If you used `DELETE` **inside a transaction**, you can of course `ROLLBACK` the transaction and everything will be fine.

Comment: dropped the table

Comment: Read this answer: **[Is there a way to recover a dropped mysql database?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-dropped-mysql-database/72760#72760)**