# Accidentally dropped the 'mysql db' in my database, how can i restore it to back?

Tags: mysql, restore

Accidentally dropped the 'mysql database' in my database, how can I restore it? I am using cpanel server.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23251/is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-dropped-mysql-database

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate @akuzminsky.  The other question is about dropping "a database," while this is appears to be about the [`mysql` system database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-database.html) -- dropping it is a much more significant problem, since the server is now in a very unstable state, assuming it's still running at all (and it certainly will not restart, if stopped).  Icebergs ahead.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to restore your databases from your backup otherwise there is no other way to retrieve your data.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. Downvoting it.